# How To Enhance This Small Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do we merge these two together to enhance the function and make it much easier to edit.

The one on the top is to fire function on Screen Re-size, and the other one is to detect the screen size on load.

**The whole Function:**

```
(function(){
  //detect the width on page load//
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width <= 770){

        $('#home-sectionB img').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB span'));
        $('.detailsBox').insertBefore($('.imagesGrid'));
        } else {
        $('#home-sectionB span').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB img')); 
        $('.imagesGrid').insertBefore($('.detailsBox'));
    }
  });
  //update the width value when the browser is resized//
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width <= 770){

        $('#home-sectionB img').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB span'));
        $('.detailsBox').insertBefore($('.imagesGrid'));
        } else {
        $('#home-sectionB span').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB img')); 
        $('.imagesGrid').insertBefore($('.detailsBox')); 
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The Top Section:

```
    (function(){
    //detect the width on page load//
     $(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width <= 770){

        $('#home-sectionB img').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB span'));
        $('.detailsBox').insertBefore($('.imagesGrid'));
        } else {
        $('#home-sectionB span').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB img')); 
        $('.imagesGrid').insertBefore($('.detailsBox'));
    }
  });
```

**The Bottom Part:**

```
  //update the width value when the browser is resized//
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width <= 770){

        $('#home-sectionB img').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB span'));
        $('.detailsBox').insertBefore($('.imagesGrid'));
        } else {
        $('#home-sectionB span').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB img')); 
        $('.imagesGrid').insertBefore($('.detailsBox')); 
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're the exact same, just create a separate function and call it on these events.

```
$(function(){
  //detect the width on page load//
  $(document).ready(handleResize);  // Notice you're already in the ready event
                                    // on this line so you can just call it here

  //update the width value when the browser is resized//
  $(window).resize(handleResize);
});

function handleResize(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width <= 770){

        $('#home-sectionB img').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB span'));
        $('.detailsBox').insertBefore($('.imagesGrid'));
        } else {
        $('#home-sectionB span').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB img')); 
        $('.imagesGrid').insertBefore($('.detailsBox'));
    }
}
```

Comment: "Notice you're already in the ready event" would be true with a call to jQuery : `jQuery(function($){ /* handle resize here */ })` ;)

Comment: The line you are pointing is just a reference to jQuery passed to an anonymous function. No dom ready here.

Comment: I am trying to apply it to this function, is't slightly a bit more complex, and i am struggling to get it working: any ideas... http://jsfiddle.net/ENRVJ/

Comment: Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/ENRVJ/2/). Remember the resize event will trigger when resizing the inner frame.

Comment: What I am doing wrong, here? it's not completely working: http://jsfiddle.net/hXNaF/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36836/discussion-between-itay-and-leo)

Answer (score 2):

**This is all you need: [LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AvEfiDA/1/edit)**

```
$(function(){  // DOM READY

    function myFunction(){   
      var insert = $(window).width()<=770 ? 'insertBefore' : 'insertAfter';
      $('#home-sectionB img')[insert]( $('#home-sectionB span') );
      $('.detailsBox')[insert]( $('.imagesGrid') );
    }
    myFunction();                   // For DOM ready
    $(window).resize( myFunction ); // For Resize

});
```

---

<sub>Which is a translation of:</sub>

```
$(function(){  // DOM READY


    function myFunction(){

        var width = $(window).width();
        if(width <= 770){       
            $('#home-sectionB img').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB span'));
            $('.detailsBox').insertBefore($('.imagesGrid'));
        } else {
            $('#home-sectionB span').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB img')); 
            $('.imagesGrid').insertBefore($('.detailsBox'));
        }

    }

    myFunction();                   // For DOM ready
    $(window).resize( myFunction ); // For Resize


});
```

<sub>**Side Note:** to prevent a total mess of inserts due to `class` elements, be more specific in assigning your selectors!</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid using a named function (based on Roko code) :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).resize(function () {   
        var insert = $(window).width() <= 770 ? 'insertBefore' : 'insertAfter';
        $('#home-sectionB img')[insert]($('#home-sectionB span'));
        $('.detailsBox')[insert]($('.imagesGrid'));
    }).resize(); // fires resize event in order to apply initial values
});
```

Comment: what did you actually do there?

Comment: You should [read the doc](http://api.jquery.com/resize/). The first call, `$(window).resize(function(){})`, just stores the function for a later use. The second call, `$(window).resize()`, triggers the resize event calling every function currently associated with it. Lastly, you can chain function calls together since `resize` returns the jQuery object itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple create a common function

```
function foo() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if(width <= 770){

        $('#home-sectionB img').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB span'));
        $('.detailsBox').insertBefore($('.imagesGrid'));
        } else {
        $('#home-sectionB span').insertBefore($('#home-sectionB img')); 
        $('.imagesGrid').insertBefore($('.detailsBox')); 
    }
}
```

And then call it in document ready and re-size

```
$(function() {
  foo();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  foo();
});
```

Comment: No need to create extra handling functions. Just write `$(window).resize(foo);`

Comment: Why wrap it in a closure?

Comment: @itay, when you said extra handling - which part you actually meant?

Comment: @Leo Writing `$(window).resize(function(){ foo(); });` instead of `$(window).resize(foo);`